# How to declare an object in the "Mastering delphi" book

Tags: delphi, indy

Im learning delphi through books and am encountering a problem in this chapter: http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+IV+Delphi+the+Internet+and+a+.NET+Preview/Chapter+19+Internet+Programming+Sockets+and+Indy/Building+Socket+Applications/#toc

It is this peace of code that gives me trouble because i dont know where to write it.

```
object IdTCPServer1: TIdTCPServer
  CommandHandlers = <
    item
      Command = 'test'
      Name = 'TIdCommandHandler0'
      ParseParams = False
      ReplyNormal.NumericCode = 100
      ReplyNormal.Text.Strings = (
        'Hello from your Indy Server')
      ReplyNormal.TextCode = '100'
    end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is part of a DFM file of a form with a non-visual component called `TIdTCPServer` on it. Just place such a component on your form and use the property editor to set the properties to the given values. For example, you have to add a command handler (using the `CommandHandlers` property) and set its `Command` property to "test".

Comment: the idTcpServer doesnt have a command property here. Is there somewhere else i should be looking?

Comment: @Eszee sorry, missed the fact that this is a property of a command handler. Edited the answer.

Comment: CommandHandlers is in the TIdCmdTCPServer component, so not sure why it's listed in the book under TIdTCPServer

Comment: You hit the nail m8 ty

Comment: @Jason: TIdTCPServer did have a CommandHandlers collection in Indy 9. It was separated out into new TIdCmdTCPServer and TIdCmdTCPClient components in Indy 10.

Answer (score 1):

That is part of the DFM file, which you don't edit directly. I just placed a TIdTCPServer on a form and the DFM shows:

```
object IdTCPServer1: TIdTCPServer
  Bindings = <>
  DefaultPort = 0
  Left = 80
  Top = 112
end
```

You can see this for yourself if you right click on your form and choose 'View as Text' (or if you inspect the .DFM files in an editor **if** you have your configuration set to save them as text.

When you start filling in more (non-default) properties of the TIdTCPServer, Delphi will store these in the DFM as well. I don't see a CommandHandlers property in my Delphi version (XE2, Indy 10.5.8.0), but yours has one (in the example).

[Edited to add] I see from your comment on another answer that you do not have a CommandHandlers property for TIdTCPServer either, this may indicate that the book author used a different Indy version than you do. You can see your version by right-clicking on any Indy component on the form.

CommandHandlers are indeed old. [Googling "tidtcpserver commandhandlers"](https://www.google.com/search?q=tidtcpserver+commandhandlers) leads to e.g. ["The CommandHandlers collection was moved to a new TIdCmdTCPServer component in Indy 10."](http://forums2.atozed.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=105) That makes me suspect you have Indy 10 and the book references 9. You'll have to find Indy 10 examples for what you want to do. [That should not be too difficult](https://www.google.com/search?q=tidtcpserver+tidcmdtcpserver).

Comment: Or you can press `ALT + F12` key shortcut to switch between form designer and form source.

Comment: right thats what i was afraid of. My version have none either. Is there a way to declare these?

Comment: Yeah i know, hes was using indy 9 and im using indy 10. This has allready caused some problems, but nothing i couldnt fix, untill now

Comment: is it still being used? or am i wasting my time learning this stuff?

Comment: Just use Indy 10. Many people do.

Comment: Youve been a great help m8 ty